# a function that properly populates members of a struct

Tags: c, loops, pointers, struct

I'm stuck. I created this code in hopes that one function can store data and then another can print it all back to me. The problem is the printing function (aka the itr8 function) gives me some of the values along with segmentation fault.

From this example, I expected the following on screen:

```
item->outptr=1.00000
item->special=0
item->outptr=2.00000
item->special=1
```

I don't care at the moment if a dot followed by any number of zeros is appended to the value of outptr. The real result when I try to execute the code is:

```
item->outptr=2.000000
item->special=1
Segmentation fault
```

I think I allocated enough memory to store the data but somewhere I think the pointers are messed up. In my itr8 function, I was trying to look for the NULL so that the program can stop after reaching the data set. after all, I allocated memory via calloc which causes each byte of allocated memory to be null to begin with.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
  double outptr;
  int special;
}set;

void itr8(set** items){
  while (items !='\0'){
    printf("item->outptr=%lf\n",(*items)->outptr);
    printf("item->special=%d\n",(*items)->special);
    items++;
  }
}

void ext(set** items,int shapeno){
  switch(shapeno){
    case 0:
      (*items)->outptr=1;
      (*items)->special=0;
      break;
    case 1:
      (*items)->outptr=2;
      (*items)->special=1;
    break;
  }
  items++;
}

int main(){
  const int numitems=100; 
  set* item=calloc(1,sizeof(set)*numitems); //allocate lots of space
  set* ritem=item; //need backup pointer since item is modified in function
  ext(&item,0);
  ext(&item,1);
  item=ritem; //restore pointer for iteration
  itr8(&item);
  free(ritem);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `items++` in `ext` does nothing. I think you mean `++*items`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues.

The first is in your `ext` function, where `items++` does not modify `item` in `main()` as you intended. Instead, it should be dereferenced once:

```
void ext(set** items,int shapeno){
  switch(shapeno){
    case 0:
      (*items)->outptr=1;
      (*items)->special=0;
      break;
    case 1:
      (*items)->outptr=2;
      (*items)->special=1;
    break;
  }
  ++*items;
}
```

The second is `itr8` which doesn't work currently. You don't want to modify `items` so you should only pass a `set *` and not a `set **`. There's also an issue with determining how many items to loop for; the check you have doesn't work because you are comparing against the null character and second because you can not do pointer comparison. One way would be to tell it when to stop iterating by passing a second `set *` argument that indicates one past the last element in `item`:

```
void itr8(set* item, set* stop){
  while (item != stop){
    printf("item->outptr=%lf\n", item->outptr);
    printf("item->special=%d\n", item->special);
    item++;
  }
}
```

And then you should call it like:

```
int main(){
  const int numitems=100; 
  set* item=calloc(numitems,sizeof(set)); //allocate lots of space
  set* ritem=item; //need backup pointer since item is modified in function
  ext(&item,0);
  ext(&item,1);
  itr8(ritem, item); // note change in how to call it
  free(ritem);
  return 0;
}
```

Note that I also changed `calloc` slightly; the first argument should be the number of elements and the second should be the size of each element.

Answer (score 0):

- `while (items !='\0')` in `itr8()` us bad because `items` won't be `NULL` before it goes to invalid area.
- `items++;` in `itr8()` will have `items` point invalid area because `item`, which `items` points before the increment, is "array of one element".
- "need backup pointer since item is modified in function" No, it won't be modified.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
  double outptr;
  int special;
}set;

void itr8(set** items){
  while ((*items)->outptr!=0.0 || (*items)->special!=0){
    printf("item->outptr=%lf\n",(*items)->outptr);
    printf("item->special=%d\n",(*items)->special);
    (*items)++;
  }
}

void ext(set** items,int shapeno){
  switch(shapeno){
    case 0:
      (*items)->outptr=1;
      (*items)->special=0;
      break;
    case 1:
      (*items)->outptr=2;
      (*items)->special=1;
    break;
  }
  (*items)++;
}

int main(void){
  const int numitems=100; 
  set* item=calloc(1,sizeof(set)*numitems); //allocate lots of space
  set* ritem=item; //need backup pointer since item is modified in function
  ext(&item,0);
  ext(&item,1);
  item=ritem; //restore pointer for iteration
  itr8(&item);
  free(ritem);
  return 0;
}
```